# How to filter D3 data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filtering

I have a JSON format dataset

```
[  
{"period":"daily", "date":"2015-04-01", "Sales_Total_Activity":0, "Sales_Emails":0},
{"period":"daily", "date":"2015-04-02", "Sales_Total_Activity":5, "Sales_Emails":4},
{"period":"weekly", "date":"2015-04-03", "Sales_Total_Activity":8, "Sales_Emails":9},
{"period":"weekly", "date":"2015-04-04", "Sales_Total_Activity":2, "Sales_Emails":6}
]
```

and would like to be able to filter it so that I only pull out the data associated with the "weekly" entry. What is the best way to do this. I've tried looking at the d3.nest implementations but have not made much headway. Is there a special function I have to write?

Thanks

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: d3.nest is for grouping like grouping the data with period daily and weekly.
I think filtering would be a good option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply some [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var array = [
        { "period": "daily", "date": "2015-04-01", "Sales_Total_Activity": 0, "Sales_Emails": 0 },
        { "period": "daily", "date": "2015-04-02", "Sales_Total_Activity": 5, "Sales_Emails": 4 },
        { "period": "weekly", "date": "2015-04-03", "Sales_Total_Activity": 8, "Sales_Emails": 9 },
        { "period": "weekly", "date": "2015-04-04", "Sales_Total_Activity": 2, "Sales_Emails": 6 }
    ],
    filtered = array.filter(function (a) { return a.period === 'weekly'; });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. Seems that my javascript is off as opposed to my D3. Back to basics.